# C# datagridview printing color every second

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
    excel = Workbook.Open("1.xls");
    sheeticerik = excel.Worksheets[0];
    for (int k = 0; k < sutun; k++)
        for (int i = 0; i < satir; i++)
        {
            string a = sheeticerik.Cells[i, k].StringValue;
            if (a.Contains("X"))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[x1].Cells[y1].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                dataGridView1.Refresh();

            }
        }
```

I want printing color to datagridview every second.And I wrote this code.But it doesn't work.Because program loop.countX1000 second waiting and immediatily printing color.Not consecutive printing.What can i do for this?

**Solution[Edit]:**

-Add a Timer control to your form. (It's in the components category)

-Set its Interval property to 45000 (the value represents milliseconds)

-Either set the Enabled property of the timer to True in the form designer, or somewhere in your code.

-Add a handler for the timer's Tick event (you can get this by double-clicking the timer)

-Inside the Tick handler, update your dataGridView

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Update DataGridView
}
```

And Use,timer1.Start();...

Comment: You are in the wrong path. You need a timer to update the datagrid.

Comment: Thnk u man...with timer its work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to print colors on a timer, try printing the colors during the DataGridView's Render() event.  Your screen will likely flicker much less too.